# How to test automatically that xsd and generated classes are synchronized?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an xml schema file and have generated classes out of that. During development the xsd can change. How can I make sure that the xsd and the generated classes are synchronized?

There is the possibility to generate the classes at build time via maven. Using this or not, I would like to be sure in a unit test.

Thanks and greetings
Steff

Comment: You could try to create xml from your generated classes and validate the generated xml against the xsd in a unit test.

Comment: I was going to say "reflection", but I'd rather go with re-generating your classes from schema as a test dependency in your build process - that way you won't have to refactor your unit test every time a change is made. So, iow, the test *is* regenerating the classes

Comment: Hi flash, that's a good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Under which circumstances can they *not* be synchronized?
While I can imagine [writing a simple JAXB plugin](http://jaxb.java.net/plugin.html) which would add a schema timestamp to the generated classes - so that you could compare timestamps in a unit test.

However I have doubt in the whole approach. Schema compilation is a a part of the build process and this must be flawless by design. You are not checking that Java files are "synchronized" with the compiled `.class` files, are you? The same should be the case for schema compilation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No I do not check the .class files itself, but I could check if the sources are representing the schema. The case is that while the product is under development the schema is not flawless. Well, the stability is growing over time.

Answer (score 0):

You force the execution of the generation every build. Or under a `Profile` not to execute it so many times and make your compilation time in development longer.

Here you can take a look at a `JAXB` plugin for generate the sources every time.

http://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home

Comment: The recommended plugin is here: http://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home